# Tool for rapidly creating Web GUI for searching database on Intranet

Tags: javascript, database, sql, intranet, database-browser

I've a database with 20 million records in 5 tables and 150 fields. It grows by about 1%/day. We want to rapidly create an Intranet website where authenticated users can browse, filter, search and download database data. The database must stay on-site. I'm looking for a tool that allows me to define the website declaratively as much as possible. I want to provide a data model for the database, lists of attributes that will be presented or can be filtered, display names for the attributes, and so forth. The tool should generate javascript widgets for search selections and provide a graphical way to layout a user's browse/filter/search/download interface. The tool must then automatically create the intermediate APIs, web app, and SQL queries. It should also create an admin GUI and manage caching in the web app. The tool should provide the software and manage the data used by the User GUI, APIs, cache, and SQL engine in this architecture.
[image]
Such a tool would be useful in many situations. While several tools provide this functionality in the cloud ([Caspio](http://pages.caspio.com), [Quickbase](http://www.quickbase.com)), despite extensive searching I cannot find any that support *on-site deployments*. Any recommendations?

I realize that I'll need to design and load the DBMS, and write code to support the Admin GUI and API.